# ExtJs Store no record found, but saved one recently

Tags: javascript, extjs

Im working on a project with Sencha Touch and the sqLite proxy you can find [here](https://github.com/shepsii/SQLite-Proxy-ST2). This website is in a phonegap environment, but it's not used when i run it from the browser.

I have this `WorkShift` model which is used by `WorkShifts` store.

**Model**:

```
Ext.define('KCS.model.WorkShift', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'WorkShiftID', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'StartDate', type: 'date' },
            { name: 'ClosureDate', type: 'date' },
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'sqlitestorage',
            dbConfig: {
                tablename: 'tbl_WorkShift',
                dbConn: KCS.util.InitSQLite.getConnection()
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And the **Store**:

```
Ext.define('KCS.store.WorkShifts', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: ['KCS.model.WorkShift'],
    config: {
        model: 'KCS.model.WorkShift',
        autoLoad: true,
        storeId: 'WorkShifts',
        pageSize: 1000
    }
});
```

Now, in my **Controller**, i want to see if there is an opened `WorkShift` (if the app crashed or was closed without closing the last `Workshift`.) So i use the launch callback like this:

```
launch : function(){
    var workShifts = Ext.getStore('WorkShifts');
    workShifts.clearFilter(true);
    var openedWS = workShifts.findBy( function( record ){
        return (record.get("StartDate") != null) && 
            (record.get("ClosureDate") == null);
    });
    if( openedWS != -1 ){
        // do stuff when an opened WS is found
    }
    else{
        // do normal stuff
    }
},
```

I did a bunch of tests, First, there is a bunch of valid entries in sqLite, and i can create WS from the store and model. There is also an entry that meets the `findBy` bool test. I've tried `workShifts.getCount()` and even `workShifts.getAllCount()` but both functions return 0. What have i done wrong?

**EDIT**:
I have also searched for things like the launch func running before the store can load data from the proxy or even cordova not firing the deviceReady callback. I have tried to apply a filter on the store and check with `getFirst()` if one survived to the test, but i think there is not even a single record to test in the first place even tho they show up in the SqLite overview from the Resources tab (in chrome webTools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the manual load function of the store and used the callback to do what i needed. The autoload parameter in the store creation is also asynchronous. That was my problem.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load

like so:

```
launch : function(){
    var workShifts = Ext.getStore('WorkShifts');
    workShifts.load({
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
            workShifts.clearFilter(true);
            var openedWS = workShifts.findBy( function( record ){
                return (record.get("StartDate") != null) && 
                    (record.get("ClosureDate") == null);
            });
            if( openedWS != -1 ){
                // do stuff when an opened WS is found
            }
            else{
                // do normal stuff
            }
        },
        scope: this
    });
},
```